# Custom filter (box) for pointclouds

Tags: ros, filter, pcl, ros-kinetic, eigen3

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I need to cut out a box (basically reimplement pcl::CropBox [link](http://docs.pointclouds.org/trunk/crop__box_8hpp_source.html#l00049)), but with the following code and the pcl::CropBox itself I do not see any difference between the source and the output clouds. Am I doing something wrong? I'm sure that there should be points within the specified min and max box boundaries.

```
auto const min = Eigen::Vector4f(-0.05702, -0.004205, 4.226287, 1.0);
auto const max = Eigen::Vector4f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

bool check_point(pcl::PointXYZ const& point)
{
    if (!pcl::isFinite(point))
    {
        return true;
    }

    return (point.x < min[0] || point.y < min[1] || point.z < min[2]) ||
        (point.x > max[0] || point.y > max[1] || point.z > max[2]);
}

void box_filter(pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr const& cloud)
{
    cloud->erase(std::remove_if(
        cloud->begin(),
        cloud->end(),
        [](auto const& x)
        {
            return check_point(x);
        }
        ));
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/299882/custom-filter-(box)-for-pointclouds/) by [Mikhail K.](https://answers.ros.org/users/35987/mikhail-k./) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2018-08-07

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Apparently erase function has another definition

```
    cloud->erase(std::remove_if(
        cloud->begin(),
        cloud->end(),
        [&c](auto const& x)
        {
            return check_point(x);
        }), cloud->end());
```

---

Originally posted by [Mikhail K.](https://answers.ros.org/users/35987/mikhail-k./) with karma: 35 on 2018-08-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0